# Checking if selected state has the entered zip code jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I want to check if the selected state contains the zip code that was entered on the input.

I am not sure where exactly is my mistake in my function.

The api that i am using is returning the correct informations but its my mistake somewhere.

```
<select id="shipping_state">
  <option value="">Select a state</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
</select>
```

So i want to get the value from the input and check if the selected state from above contains that zip code, if it doesnt to show the user error message and if it does to continue

```
<input type="text" id="shipping_postcode" name="shipping_postcode" placeholder="ZIP" class="input-text">
```

And this is my function with jQuery

```
function is_int(value) {
        if ((parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
   // $('#checkout-button').off("click");
  $('#checkout-button:contains("Submit")').click(function () {
    //console.log("click!");
    var state = "";
    var postalCode = "";
    var zipInputVal = $("#shipping_postcode").val();

    var el = $("#shipping_postcode");

    var stateCheck = '';

    var stateSelect = $('#shipping_state').val();
// Did they type five integers?
    if ((el.val().length == 5) && (is_int(el.val()))) {

        // Call Ziptastic for information
        $.ajax({
        url: "https://zip.getziptastic.com/v2/US/" + el.val(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result, success) {        
            console.log(result);

            stateCheck = result.state;
        },
        error: function(result, success) {
            alert("Your zip code doesnt match with your state");
        }
        });
    }
    else if(stateSelect === stateCheck) {
        alert('done');
    }
    else {
        alert('Not correct');
    }


});
```

Comment: Pretty sure it does not go into the error callback - that would only happen if the API indicated an error via the HTTP status code. You need to handle both cases in your success callback.

Comment: it is actually working [https://jsfiddle.net/qz2ydr0g/](https://jsfiddle.net/qz2ydr0g/)

Comment: @NidhinChandran Its only doing console.log on the results from the entered zipcode, but the entered zipcode does not match with the selected state. I need to check if the selected state match with the entered zipcode

Comment: but i got this 'Your zip code doesnt match with your state' alert when i used zip '12363' with 'Arkansas'

Comment: @NidhinChandran Thats because that zip code is not true, i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the conditions in wrong place.
Check this

```js
function is_int(value) {
  if ((parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
// $('#checkout-button').off("click");
$('#checkout-button:contains("Submit")').click(function() {
  //console.log("click!");
  var state = "";
  var postalCode = "";
  var zipInputVal = $("#shipping_postcode").val();

  var el = $("#shipping_postcode");

  var stateCheck = '';

  var stateSelect = $('#shipping_state').val();
  // Did they type five integers?
  if ((el.val().length == 5) && (is_int(el.val()))) {

    // Call Ziptastic for information
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://zip.getziptastic.com/v2/US/" + el.val(),
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(result, success) {
        console.log(result);

        stateCheck = result.state;
        if (stateSelect === stateCheck) {
          alert('done');
        } else {
          alert('Not correct');
        }
      },
      error: function(result, success) {
        alert("Your zip code doesnt match with your state");
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('5 chars required');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="shipping_state">
  <option value="">Select a state</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="shipping_postcode" name="shipping_postcode" placeholder="ZIP" class="input-text">
<button id="checkout-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution for your issue. Use below code inside you success callback function

```
stateCheck = result.state;
if (stateSelect === stateCheck) {
    alert('done');
} else {
    alert('Not correct');
}
```

And remove else if condition of this `if ((el.val().length == 5) && (is_int(el.val()))) {`
line. This will work for sure.